# I18n translation of site_name not working

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have installed [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n), changed `settings.php` according to this guide, set language detection to url and cleared cache.

Then on site config page, I set the url prefix to English and all UI changed to English. Then I updated the Site Name to something English.

Then I repeated the above steps for a local language.

But it looks like changing the url path prefix each time gives me identical results regarding Site Name, i.e. the Site Name is changing each time I update it, no matter which language path is chosen.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. In table "variable" the site_name is just one. I never used `i18n` before, no idea how it should look here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To translate a Drupal 7 Site name you have to activate `Variable translation` module (which is in the same package as i18n) and the required ones (like `Variable store`).

After you install these modules, go to `Configuration -> Multilingual settings -> Variables` tab and choose **Site name** (`?q=admin/config/regional/i18n/variable`),Then go to `Configuration -> System -> Site information` (`q=admin/config/system/site-information`) and select the language you want. Change the **Site name** field and save.

You'll find the translated site name in `variable_store` table.

Comment: I have done exactly like you explained but on site information variable does not appear please suggest ?