# For multilingual sites, where are translated variables for the non-default language stored?

Tags: i18n-l10n, features, configuration

I'm managing deployment using the Features module.

Using Strongarm, I have added the `site_403` (access denied page) variable to my feature.  However, this only contains the value for the default language (in my case, English).  I also have "translated" this URL into Japanese using the i18n **Variable translation** submodule, but I cannot find where this translated `site_403` variable is stored in order to add it to my feature.

How can I add translated variables (via the i18n module) to a feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to this [I18n translation of site_name not working](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39082/i18n-translation-of-site-name-not-working/39093#39093)

You need to enable 'Variable translation', 'Variable store' modules. Then you need to specify which variables you want to translate from Configuration -> Multilingual settings -> Variables. With this you would be able to translate your Site Information variables in different languages.

Now in Features, you can export translated variables from the section 'REALM VARIABLES'.